# SQl server TVF CLR function returns  row index?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlclr

I have this simple C#  code which is used by Sql Server to return `TVF`:

```
[SqlFunction(FillRowMethodName = "FillRow3")]
public static IEnumerable GetCsv(string csv)
{
    string[] arr = csv.Split(',');
    return arr;
}

public static void FillRow3(Object obj, out int val, out int index)
{
    val = int.Parse((string)obj) ;
    index =  ??? <----------?
}
```

Hoever - I  want to return a table which has 2 columns :  `( val,index)`

How can I return for each row , its index ( 0-based) according to `arr`

(`obj` is the *row* from `arr`.)

*p.s - 
I can create an array of `MyItem` which will contain [value,index] in the `GetCsv` method.

And then  - obj row ( val+index) will be visible to `FillRow3` method.
But I don't want to do that.*

Comment: see this post may be helpful to you http://wfjanjua.blogspot.com/2012/05/sql-clr-table-valued-function-returns.html

Comment: @WaqarJanjua thanks but it doesnt help much.He doesnt analyze item location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
[SqlFunction(FillRowMethodName = "FillRow3")]
public static IEnumerable GetCsv(string csv)
{
    string[] arr = csv.Split(',');
    return arr.Select((x, i) => Tuple.Create(x, i));
}

public static void FillRow3(Object obj, out string val, out int index)
{
    var input = (Tuple<string, int>)obj;
    val = input.Item1;
    index = input.Item2;
}
```

Notice, that no static variables are needed. If you don't think static state inside of SQL Server is a problem please research this issue.

Comment: I kind of ignored that one because I cannot find any reason. Why do you pose this constraint?

Comment: cause I wanted to see if I can handle the index in the seconds method.,

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

I wanted to produce a counter in :

```
public static void FillRow3(Object obj, out int val, out int index)
{

}
```

But it must be static .

So I tried creating a static field :

```
public static   int g = 0;
public static void FillRow2(Object obj, out int val, out int index)
{
    val = (int.Parse((string) obj)*2);
    int h = g;
   index = h++;
}
```

but then SQL shouted :

> CREATE ASSEMBLY failed because type 'Class1' in safe assembly 'MyDll2'
>   has a static field 'g'. Attributes of static fields in safe assemblies
>   must be marked  readonly in Visual C#, ReadOnly in Visual Basic, or
>   initonly in Visual C++ and intermediate language.

But if I will have a `readonly int` - I *won't* be able to change it.

So I created a wrapper reference object to that `int`.

the *reference* won't chage , the *Int* will... :)

So my final solution was :

```
  public class MyCounter
    {
        public  int cnt;
    }  


    public static readonly MyCounter mc = new MyCounter();

    public static void FillRow2(Object obj, out int val, out int index)
    {
        val = (int.Parse((string) obj)*2);

        index = mc.cnt++;
    }
```

And..................

[image]

Comment: By using static state you are introducing a race condition between concurrent threads using your function. You *will* get incorrect results if SQL Server executes your query in parallel or executes multiple queries.

Comment: @usr I use lock inside `GetCsv`. this will allow only 1 thread do its job - one at a time. However , each ignition should start from 0 . which it doesnt(currently) it starts from the last integer....I should see how im fixing it.

Comment: First, GetCsv is called. Then, FillRow is called repeatedly. You don't protect both using locking, you only protect GetCsv. Just get rid of the static state. Please don't put such code on the internet. I'm tempted to answer this question properly but you can find correct examples on the web: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38710/Some-Utility-Functions-using-SQL-Server-2005-CLR-H *Please* delete this post as people will paste this literally and shoot themselves in the foot.

Comment: @usr How does your link suppose to help ? It has just a simple code , no  Indesx situation... I dont understand why _you_ pasted it

Comment: @usr The documentation on this topic is sucks.  where does it say that first getcsv is called , and then FillRow is called repeatedly ?  if thats the situation , So  I **MUST** fill indexes at the GetCsv method.

Comment: I did not downvote. The sample code can be found searching for "IEnumerable Split". The best docs I could find are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131103.aspx The examples look good to me.